# Children/teen driven through sandstorm(?) to parallel universe/other time to escape war/catastrophe?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

This was a live action movie/TV series/miniseries? Not sure which. Certainly premiered in 21st century, probably after 2010 but I have no clue more specifically.

Parent(s) paid/bribed? some military looking types to drive their beloved through some kind of semi-permanent sandstorm-looking thing to take them to a parallel universe or other time period to escape some war or catastrophe. The driving aspect of the plot was similar to that aspect of [Monster Hunter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6475714/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0), but there were no monsters or dinosaurs on the other side.

The new arrival(s) were subjected to a barrage of questions. That's all I can remember about it; I didn't actually watch the whole thing myself. I am asking because I suspect the above thing is the answer to [this closed question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250772).

Comment: If it's not Terra Nova then only other possible match I have that vaguely fits the description is Interstellar: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/

Comment: Interstellar has a sandstorm in it, and it has a wormhole in it. But in the story I'm thinking of, I am quite certain the driving in a land vehicle (which was not a pickup truck) through the sandstorm was HOW they got to the parallel universe or other time. Like that aspect of Monster Hunter. The people in the vehicle were definitely met by a bunch of other people who were already there. Not just one frozen astronaut who looked a lot like Matt Damon. And there were no dinosaurs. This story was by no means as well known as Terra Nova or Interstellar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like [*Shadow and Bone*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2403776/), a 2021 Netflix series based on a young adult series. More information available on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_and_Bone_(TV_series)).

It's a TV series. In an alternate Czarist Russia (like *Game of Thrones* is in an alternate Europe + Morocco) there's a giant storm area, populated by monsters, which divides that country and it's permanent. People can go through it at great risk, they have to pay professional guides to have a chance of success. The side of the country where the Czar/ruler/capital city (alternate Moscow) isn't, talks about formally declaring independence, which is an escape of sorts.

Comment: Well I'm embarrassed that what I saw was way more recent than I supposed, but this is obviously what I was remembering, so, checked.

Comment: Site note: I always wonder where the spelling “czar” came from as it suggests the wrong pronunciation. The transcription by usual rules from Russian (or Bulgarian) is “tsar”.